# Receive messages from a window you only have the HWND of?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm using an API for games. It creates the window for me but there are a few messages I'd like to do something with. For example, when the screen is resizing I want to display a black screen. Essentially, I have the HWND of my main window and would like to listen to the messages and have them go through my custom WndProc before or after they are processed, I just want to know when the window receives messages like WM_SIZE or something.

Is there an API for this?

Thanks

Comment: This might be a job for [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are in the same process with the window that you want to intercept WM_SIZE, you can simply replace WndProc by [`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `GWLP_WNDPROC`. Note that you must pass the other messages to the original WndProc.

However, if you are in the different process, then you need to find a way using hooks such as [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: +1; subclassing is likely the way to go here. FYI - SetWindowLong is deprecated for WNDPROC and other pointer-size values; use SetWindowLongPtr for compat with both Win32 and Win64 - have edited answer to reflect this.

Comment: BTW: the MSDN link still points to SetWindowLong instead of SetWindowLongPtr